# rbs + file server + deduplication

Tags: rbs, file-server

I wonder if this combination works.
Also, deduplication is per site collection? For example, if two site collections have the same document, will this document be twice on the file server?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they would still exist multiple times.

It sounds like you might want to employ the Link to Document content type in your libraries that will let you create a pointer reference to an existing item.

Comment: Nope. I need to use deduplication. Otherwise, I need to give access to other files in other sites and the 50.000 unique permissions are just round a corner.